# Preventing XSS in ASP.Net Webforms: why is Validate Request not enough?

Tags: security, xss, webforms

I'm looking for ways to protect our website from XSS attacks. At this point I am concerned about sanitizing/protecting the **input only**. I am aware of the need to encode the output, but that's out of the scope of this question.

A few things to bear in mind:

- My web does not accept user-generated HTML at all.
- I have Validate Request set to true.

I know that Microsoft [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649487.aspx#pagguidelines0001_inputdatavalidation) not to rely on on Validate Request exclusively. However, I'd like to know *why*. Embarking on an input sanitization project will involve a fair amount of time and money which I need to justify to the business.

I have been researching into actual examples of how to attack the Validate Request protection. All I have come up with is [this](http://www.securitysift.com/xss-and-cross-site-scripting-with-a-little-help-from-asp-net-and-ie9/). However, I have been unable to reproduce it on my site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Microsoft recommends that you don't rely on Validate Request because

> Only you can define what represents good input for your application.

I recommend you read [How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx) guideline. This is possibly the best thing I have read from Microsoft on the topic of XSS.

Another thing you can use to sanitize input is [Microsoft Web Protection Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126075030/http://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/80289). It is easy to integrate it into existing applications and this is a quite mature project I personally rely on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I was aware of the 'AntiXss' library as well. It's just a question of estimating actual effort vs cost so I can justify it to the business. That's why I needed a bit more information as to why Validate Request is not enough.

Comment: @mkorman no one will tell you exactly why you cannot rely on this standard ASP.NET feature, because answer on this question depends on context where you want to use it. It is up to you to decide if you need or don't need additional input validation.

Comment: Fair enough. I would then rephrase my question to "when is Validate Request enough and when is it not?". Microsoft's statement seems to indicate that it is *never* enough, which means that context is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Cross site scripting can be fixed by encoding incoming parameters and also by validating them with a customized regex.

For example: `Encode.forhtml(inputparam)`

There are several types of context based encoding using OWASP encoder. If you're not sure about encoder or validation patterns, try the cross site scripting validator below to make sure the right approach to a fix.

XSS validator for Java: http://fixforscrossite.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/